# Characters not decoded properly using Jsoup and PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, character-encoding, phantomjs, jsoup

This is the thing, I'm using PhantomJS and Selenium in Python to render pages, this is the code:

```
import sys, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\\..\\chromedriver'

section = sys.argv[1]
path = sys.argv[2]
links = sys.argv[3]

listOfLinks = []
file = open(links, 'r')
for link in file:
    listOfLinks.append(link)

dr = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

cont = 0
for link in listOfLinks:
    try:
        dr.get(link)

        # Wait.
        element = WebDriverWait(dr, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_img-zoom"))
        )

        time.sleep(1)

        htmlPath = path + section + "_" + str(cont) + ".html"

        # Write HTML.
        file = open(htmlPath, 'w')
        file.write(dr.page_source)
        file.close()

        cont = cont + 1
    except:
        print("Exception")

dr.quit()
```

This code creates a HTML of the links received as parameter.

This file is parsed by Jsoup in Java:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse( file, "UTF-8" );
```

However, special characters as '€', 'á', 'é', 'í', etc are not decoded properly and they're being replaced by '?'. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try Document document = Jsoup.parse( file, "ISO-8859-1" );

Comment: @Uzochi yep, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found by [Uzochi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176992/uzochi)

> Try Document document = Jsoup.parse( file, "ISO-8859-1" );